# How to show horizental progressbar

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, android-progressbar

I want to show Horizontal progress bar. In my code i do this with circle Progress bar. I need to show a horizontal Progress bar while searching the Text from a file.

```
    public  void search(){
    pd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            haspmap = Searching(folderNameSelected, langTypeSelected,searchingWord.toLowerCase().trim());

            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    RecordText.setText(Recordsize+ " Results found");
                    //              int d=haspmap.get(resultRefList).size();
                    listAdapter = new MylistAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                            haspmap.get("resultArray"), haspmap.get("suratName"),haspmap.get("ayahnumber"));
                    SurahList.setAdapter(listAdapter);

                    hideKeyboard(inputSearch);
                    inputSearch.setSelection(inputSearch.getText().length());
                    pd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    searchedList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });

        }
    }).start();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Modify and use this :

```
int progress_status = 0;

 ProgressDialog progressBar = new ProgressDialog(view.getContext());
                    progressBar.setCancelable(false);
                    progressBar.setMessage("Please Wait...");
                    progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                    progressBar.setProgress(0);
                    progressBar.setMax(100);
                    progressBar.show();
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            if(progress_status < 100) {
                                loginUser(num, code);

                                // Update the progress bar
                                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        progressBar.setProgress(progress_status);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }).start();
```

Answer (score 2):

Best example for progress bar:

1. [Horizontal Progress Bar](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/)
2. [Progressbar](http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/progressBarExample.html)
3. [NewStyleprogressbar](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/09/android-progress-bar-example.html#.UrwJJPtbzMo)

Comment: @M D .... Thanks a lot for guiding me , I have to make a custion Progress bar, confused about that

Answer (score 1):

By default, the progress bar is a spinning wheel (an indeterminate indicator). To change to a horizontal progress bar, apply the Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal style, like so:

```
<ProgressBar
     style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
     ... />
```

And please check this link. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html

Comment: style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal" is a better solution, because it takes the style from the current theme.